# looking for advice on creating a wizard that asks questions based on previous answers

Tags: javascript, database

Not fishing for code because I want to build/maintain this myself.  I have a need to ask a question.  Based on the question's answer, I want to ask more questions and eventually submit the responses in an email.

Are you male or female?  (user clicks male)
Are both of your parents living? (user clicks yes)

with a large set of questions, but only certain ones get asked based on your choices.  Ex: if you click male, you won't be asked if you have ever been pregnant.  (and no I'm not taking people who have had sex changes into the equation).

Ideally, I'd like to build it out so that it's fairly easy to change the questions and their relation to the other questions.  Would this be easier in javascript or with a database?

Comment: If I understand your need correctly, I would say with a database. At least then there's a chance that you could swap-out questions. But it does sound like an ambitious project. MikeW is right: probably all 3 involved, plus jQuery and AJAX and...

Comment: This question is just too vague. You'd probably need both Javascript and a database, and PHP or something similar as well. They all do different things.

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness, I had a feeling that might be the case.  I didn't want to come across as one of those guys I've been seeing a lot of lately asking a question that is obviously from work or from school :)  I'm really just looking for a starting point more than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It depends."

What does it depend on? Glad you asked.

You can do this purely in javascript by dynamically building the DOM up to match the user's choices as they navigate through the choices available per question *so long as the page does not refresh or relocate*.

If it does refresh or relocate, for modern browsers you can use localstorage which will temporarily hold some data. You could also store it in a temporary Session variable on your server.

However, you cannot (to my knowledge) send an email purely from client side javascript. There must be a server that you eventually post all of your choices to in order to fire off the email.

This is where the database comes in. If you wish to save these choices and emails, then you are going to need a database. If you do not care to save the choices, then a database will have no use.